# Making Applet game Multiplayer

Tags: java, sockets, applet, multiplayer

```
            This is a intro to my problem Skip if you don't care.
```

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

I have a java applet and I'm brand new to java. first semester of CSIS10a intro to java. me and my friends had a project to make a java applet game for our final. We finished with an "A" and in my opinion it was the best one there. Think asteroids but a side-scroller like R-Type kinda. My mathy friend did the all the physics in it, some pretty cool stuff I got to say, my other friend was the art guy and FX drew the ship and did the explosions and stuff, also pretty awesome. I'm the "code-monkey" I guess because I have a heavy background in networking and I'm a System admin for Linux servers. So I know bash like the back of my hand, java came pretty easily to me (much easier then my peer I should say). so after the final They said "Hey we should Put this online and make it multiplayer!", and of course I said, "Sure that should be simple enough! set up a java server and have them send X & Y coordinates back and forth. make getter and setter for the X&Y and were in business!" and of course I was wrong lol.

So... after a month of trying to figure it out and posting little questions on here every week I decided to post the whole problem on here and see if I can get some guidance.

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

```
                                End of intro
```

I've converted a simple chat client/server system(based on the echo server examples) to send ints instead of strings to the server and the server send the ints to the second client. so far the client is still a application and not part of the applet and we've been testing it by calling the clients method in the game that we run separately. I can't figure out how to run the client when the game starts up because every time I try and make a method that creates a socket the game freezes and doesn't connect. I think its because the socket is like a infinite loop that it never continues on with the rest of the code. so I looked into threads, I make a new thread that makes a connection and the game is separate but guess what? the game freezes and connects or it plays and doesn't connect lol.

Any help would be great I have no idea what to do, and im out of ideas and idk if you want me to post all of my code because its pretty lengthy lol but ill post my client class if you want...

```
package Connection;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

class client extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

static String address = "127.0.0.1";
static JLabel text, clicked;
static JButton button;
static JPanel panel;
static JTextField textField;
static JTextArea textArea;
Socket socket = null;
PrintWriter out = null;
BufferedReader in = null;

client() {
    text = new JLabel("Send Text Over Socket:");
    textField = new JTextField(20);
    textArea = new JTextArea(5, 20);
    button = new JButton("Send");
    button.addActionListener(this);

    panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    panel.setBackground(Color.white);
    getContentPane().add(panel);
    panel.add("Center", textField);
    panel.add("North", textArea);
    panel.add("South", button);
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    Object source = event.getSource();

    if (source == button) {
        String text = textField.getText();
        out.println(text);
        textField.setText(new String(""));
        try {
            String line = in.readLine();
            if (line != null)
                client.textArea.append("Text received :" + line + "\n");
            else
                client.textArea.append("Welcome To James World Messager!");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            client.textArea.append("Read failed\n");
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
}

public void listenSocket() {
    try {
        socket = new Socket(address, 4444);
        out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                socket.getInputStream()));
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        client.textArea.append("Unknown host: " + address + "\n");
        System.exit(1);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        client.textArea.append("No I/O\n");
        System.exit(1);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    client frame = new client();
    frame.setTitle("Client Program");

    WindowListener l = new WindowAdapter() {
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    };

    frame.addWindowListener(l);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.listenSocket();
}
```

}

This is the code I tried to implement into the game as a class I could call on but no dice...

```
package Game;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class tclient extends Thread{
 String address = "***.***.***.***;
 Socket socket = null;
 PrintWriter out = null;
 BufferedReader in = null;
 tclient tclient[];

 public tclient(Socket socket, tclient[] tclient) {
    this.socket = socket;
    this.tclient = tclient;
    }
 public void run(){
 try{
   socket = new Socket(address, 1234);
   out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
   in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
 } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
   System.out.println(e);
 } catch  (IOException e) {
   System.out.println(e); 
 }
 }
 //    public void sendX(int x){
 //        out.println(x);
 //     }
 //    public void sendY(int Y){
 //        out.println(Y);
 //     }
 }
```

Comment: With your current code as written, you won't be able to tell what is happening, or where your freezing. Consider either using a debugger and setting break points, or more simply, sprinkling your code with System.out.println(...) statements that tell you what the state of certain fields are as the program runs.

Comment: If I recall, getInputStream blocks, which would explain the freezing you described.  So it's likely you're not sending the data correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I think one problem you might be running across (or will run across soon) is that Java applets [aren't allowed to make TCP connections to any server other than the server that hosts the applet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/security.html).  So unless you are running a web server on localhost and pointing your web browser at localhost as well, a TCP connection to 127.0.0.1 from the applet will throw an exception and not work.

Presumably in order to make multiplayer work on a Java applet you'd need a separate server process running on the same machine as the web server.  The various Java applets could then all connect to this server process (since they are allowed to connect to the web server's IP address) and the server process would be responsible for forwarding information from one Java applet to the other, as necessary.

Comment: I have a java server but it wasn't running on the same machine the applet was being hosted but I'll be hosting both the applet and java server on the same machine.

Comment: well, the applet usually runs on the client/players machine.  They download the applet and run it on their browser.  So visitors of the server wont be able to use the applet.

Comment: so there is no way to have applets have multiplayer? I know it can be done. I've used it before!

Comment: It can be done, it's just that the game server has to run on the same machine as the web server that serves the applets, and the applets have to connect via TCP (since connecting via TCP to the same IP address that the applets were served from is all they are allowed to do, networking-wise)